# How to increase height of textArea dynamically upto 3 line height (Just like whatsApp message box) in titanium appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, jtextarea, appcelerator-alloy

I need to implement dynamic height of textarea that expects a user to type comment. I have seen the interaction of textArea like this on WhatsApp. 
The text area will be initially of 1 line height later on as the user enters the text it should increase. But the text area should not be increased more than 3 line height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, I used a workaround to achieve that.

```
var _lines = textFieldValue.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length;
if(_lines > 3 || textFieldValue.length > 90) {
$.textAreaDescriptionId.height = "80dp";
} else {
  $.textAreaDescriptionId.height = Titanium.UI.SIZE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
$.textArea.height = $.textArea.font.fontSize * 3 // plus some padding
```

Add a padding because otherwise it will be too small. The fontSize * 3 is the minimum you should have for 3 lines.

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments. There is currently no way to set maxLines for a TextField in Titanium. So it won't work dynamically.

Ticket and PR to include this feature:

- https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5653
- https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/9927

Comment: I think he's asking to set a dynamic height like the field should look like a single-line field initially, and as the user continues to type in, it should expand to 3 lines tall automatically. Not sure any easy way to do this without having **maxLines** property for TextArea

Comment: Ah, I see. You are right, there is currently no option for a TextField to set maxLines. I'll set up a PR!

Comment: The only way at present is if we wrap a **TextArea** with **width=SIZE** & **top/bottom=0** inside a View of fixed height of 3 lines tall. It will certainly create a resizable TextArea with just a limitation that other UI elements will have to consider the height of this TextArea's parent View.

Comment: Thanks, @PrashantSaini for your suggestions. I do not want to limit the number of characters in the text field. I just want to limit the height, the user should still be able to enter text.